# How do I run code on Excel startup (not workbook_open)?

Tags: excel, file

I'm looking for a way to run code on opening an excel file, but not from the workbook_open method.

Like with a specific name "main_tables.xlsx", and excel on opening, runs custom macros, that are not from the said file.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Add-In.

Create an add-in with the following code in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private WithEvents app As Application

' This will run when any workbook is opened.
Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    ' Check if this add-in is opening versus any other workbook.
    If Not Wb Is Me Then
        ' Another workbook is opening - do something...
        MsgBox Wb.Name
    End If
End Sub

' This will run when the add-in workbook is opened.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Set the app variable so that we can listen for WorkbookOpen event
    Set app = Application
End Sub
```

Save this as an add-in in the add-in folder (usually C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft|AddIns) by choosing File -> Save As and selecting the Excel Add-in (*.xlam) file type.

Then in File -> Options -> Add-ins choose Manage Excel Add-ins and press Go.... This brings up a list of add-ins to start automatically. Tick the add-in you just created.

Now, when you open any workbook, the add-in code will run.